# is it good to use sscanf for parsing string

Tags: c++

I have been using sscanf() in my parser to get some css like tokens such as color code some variations below;

```
#FDC69A
#ff0
orange
```

Example code will be;

```
int r g b;
cosnt char* s = "#FAFAFA";
if(sscanf(s, "#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) == 3){
// color code ok
}
```

My preferred language for current project is c++, I think sscanf can be faster than regular character by character parsing and overall code will be bug free & minimal still it may have portability issues across different compilers.

A thing I noticed is, popular of open source project do not use sscanf for tokenizing input buffers instead they do it char by char, it is a bad programming practice to use sscanf in parsing that i am following?

Comment: The best strategy for reading data from your files depends on the format of the data in the input file. It'll be hard to suggest something that will work for your needs without knowing more details.

Comment: @RSahu my input file is can be as complex as html but i am only using sscanf for parsing some sections in it

Comment: FWIW, Boost Spirit Qi has a pretty [rich feature set](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1264d5c987323839). Disclaimer: my sample is probably not ideal.

Comment: "is it good to use sscanf for parsing string" - no, it isn't.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant i would have picked that as best answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem with `sscanf` (as well as `scanf` and `fscanf`) is that numeric overflow causes undefined behavior. For example:

```
const char *s = "999999999999999999999999999999";
int n;
sscanf(s, "%d", &n);
```

The C standard says exactly nothing about how this code behaves. It might set `n` to some arbitrary value, it might report an error, or it might crash.

(In practice, existing implementations are likely to behave sensibly, for some value of "sensibly".)

Answer (score 1):

`if(sscanf(s, "#%02x%02x%02x", &r, &g, &b) == 3)` is robust... nothing to worry about there.

Historically, the big concern with those functions was that someone might specify a format flag that doesn't match the argument (e.g. `%d` not given an `int*`)... many modern compilers have enough validation to avoid accidents like that.

Still, C++ has iostreams, and people tend to use those for many I/O and parsing operations as the stream destructors automatically flush and close files and release descriptors, they're type safe, extensible to user-defined types, you can generally reuse parsing/output code for any type of stream, and they're often convenient.  They'd be significantly more tedious for your specific test above though.

If you've noticed lots of OSS programs scanning character by character, it may be because:

- They're doing more complex parsing - where they want to branch to different parsing logic after reading individual characters, or

  - In your code you have a firm expectation of what to expect, so it's reasonable to do a `sscanf` to test that, but if you were writing say a compiler it'd be too slow to try a huge `if`/`else` list of hundreds `sscanf` attempts to recognise tokens.

- Relevant for `scanf`, `fscanf` but *not* `sscanf` - avoid scanning too far so they can [ungetc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ungetc), which (from memory) is only portably guaranteed to work for 1 character.

Comment: After replacing sscanf() from my code i noticed that my program not crashing in test cases where it did before! I think that may be a side effect of using sscanf

Comment: @treemonster19: well, hundreds of thousands of programs use `sscanf` just fine, but if any one call has a small mistake, it could well cause a crash or data corruption.  With streams - if code compiles it probably won't crash, but people manage to screw up their processing logic often enough so it still doesn't do what's hoped (e.g. by not even checking for errors, by testing `eof` even before they've tried to read anything, due to confusing usage for things like continuing after a parsing error, or using io manipulators robustly).

Comment: actually i do not have control over what is going to be an input.

Comment: @treemonster19: that's fine... that's what your "== 3" handles... each `sscanf` should generally check that the expected number of conversions have succeeded.  For robust usage, it's sometimes useful to use `%n` as well to keep track of how many characters have been parsed, and/or to use a trailing `%c` to make sure there's nothing extra and unwanted on the line.  Summarily, `sscanf` can be used robustly for unknown and untrusted input as long as you tick every single box, every single time.